# Does PHP have a feature to simulate file writing into a variable instead of the disk?

Tags: php, security, phpword

I am using a library ([PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/)) to process data which [requires writing the file to disk](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Writer/Word2007.php#L96). However, some of the information being handled is potentially sensitive, and this system is only meant to process the data and send it along to where it will be securely stored. For this reason, I want to avoid writing any of the data to the disk and only work with the data in memory.

So my question is: Does PHP have some feature I can leverage that will satisfy the library's requirement for a writable file location without letting the data become accessible on the filesystem, and will allow me to retrieve the file as a variable? If not, is there a workaround I'm perhaps not thinking of for this dilemma? I am using PHP7 on a Debian linux system, but an OS-agnostic solution would still be preferred.

Comment: `php://memory` and `php://temp` or possibly `php://output` buffer it and then get it after.

Comment: Please be aware that some of the suggestions of AbraCadaver may actually store the data in a file, under some circumstances. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Yes, `temp` might if memory is full.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @AbraCadaver, I found a workable solution.

PhpWord internally writes to a temporary location while creating the file, so a configuration change in that is required to avoid it writing the data temporarily to the disk.

I added `tempDir = "php://memory"` to the `phpword.ini.dist` configuration file for the library so that it writes the temporary file in memory instead of a temporary directory on the filesystem.

Now obviously I also needed to do something similar for the location it would write the final file to as well. Using php://memory wasn't an option for this since PhpWord closes the file descriptor after finishing writing. So I had to abuse php://output a bit instead. Here is approximately what I ended up doing in my code:

```php
$PhpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $PhpWord -> addSection();
$section -> addText("Test text");

// Write the document
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PhpWord, 'Word2007');
ob_start();
$writer -> save('php://output');
$document = ob_get_clean(); // Document file is now contained in $document
```